# How to install bnetd in Lubuntu from command line?

Tags: server, lubuntu, make, makefile, lxterminal

I am trying to install bnetd on lubuntu and i got error compiling it (I have never compiled anything yet)
I execute this at the terminal:

```
loading cache ./config.cache
checking host system type... Invalid configuration `x86_64-pc-linux-gnuoldld': machine `x86_64-pc' not recognized

checking target system type... Invalid configuration `x86_64-pc-linux-gnuoldld': machine `x86_64-pc' not recognized

checking build system type... Invalid configuration `x86_64-pc-linux-gnuoldld': machine `x86_64-pc' not recognized

checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
configure: error: no acceptable cc found in $PATH
```

And from the command:

```
ls -l /home/andrey/Desktop/bnetd-0.4.25/
```

I get this:

```
total 132
-rw-r--r--  1 andrey andrey 50287 яну 21  2002 CHANGELOG
drwxr-xr-x  2 andrey andrey  4096 май 24 23:04 conf
-rw-r--r--  1 andrey andrey 17992 апр 26  2001 COPYING
-rw-r--r--  1 andrey andrey  6326 яну 15  2002 CREDITS
drwxr-xr-x  2 andrey andrey  4096 май 24 23:04 docs
drwxr-xr-x  2 andrey andrey  4096 май 24 23:04 files
-rw-r--r--  1 andrey andrey  4723 апр 26  2001 INSTALL
drwxr-xr-x  2 andrey andrey  4096 май 24 23:04 man
drwxr-xr-x  3 andrey andrey  4096 май 24 23:04 packaging
-rw-r--r--  1 andrey andrey  4997 ное 29  2001 README
drwxr-xr-x  2 andrey andrey  4096 май 24 23:04 scripts
drwxr-xr-x 15 andrey andrey  4096 май 24 23:04 src
-rw-r--r--  1 andrey andrey  5696 яну 17  2002 TODO
```

And in the tutorial I am reading it's all fine. I cant understand where is my error. Also i cant run make command because i still don't have the make file...
I am using LXTerminal

Comment: Could you add the output of the next command please? `ls -l /home/andrey/Desktop/bnetd-0.4.25/`

Comment: Just type `ls` and then choose a file like and execute it `./"filename"`

Comment: Thanks. Could you add the link of the package? So we can test it.

Comment: Done. | What do you mean to get file like i must configure it and then compile. Sorry for my not-understanding but I am very new to Linux systems.

Comment: [link](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~owend/free/bnetd.html)

Comment: I have executed the command - question edited

Comment: Why did you removed the previous command? Also, after what command do you get that output? Its difficult for us understand that.

Comment: @Andrey If my answer has been useful, you can [mark it as accepted](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1137/how-do-i-accept-an-answer). So your question remains as answered. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `configure` file is placed in the `src` folder. To install it:

1. From the terminal go to your `src` folder:

   `cd /home/andrey/Desktop/bnetd-0.4.25/src/`
2. Configure the installation:

   `./configure`
3. Compile it:

   `make`
4. Install it:

   `sudo make install`

Now you should have installed [the application](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~owend/free/bnetd.html) correctly

---

**To have in mind:** inside the compressed package you can see the `INSTALL` file, it contains instruction for the installation of that specific software. So the next time open it ;)